# Dúvida sobre JOIN do LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Existe uma ordem certa pra se usar o join?
Exemplo, tenho duas listas: categories e products, devo primeiro usar a cláusula from com o Categories ou Products? E depois no Join?
Exemplo:

```
    var stockQuery = from category in categories
                     join product in products on category equals product.Category into prodGroup
                     select new { Key = category.Name, Products = prodGroup };
```

O código acima funciona normalmente, mas o código abaixo não, por que?

```
    var stockQuery = from product in products
                     join category in categories on product.Category equals category into prodGroup
                     select new { Key = category.Name, Products = prodGroup };
```

Mostra o erro que `category` não tá no mesmo contexto, mas mesmo assim não entendo por que ele não está...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após efectuar um join, duas variáveis estão em contexto: o item seleccionado na cláusula `from` e o grupo criado com a cláusula `join`. Ou seja, na seguinte query:

```
from product in products
join category in categories on product.Category equals category into prodGroup
select /** TODO **/
```

As variáveis disponíveis são `product` e `prodGroup` - o produto e as categorias correspondentes.

A variável `category` não está disponível - mas não precisa de estar, pois seria igual a `product.Category`. Eis como resolver o `select`

```
select new { Key = product.Category.Name, Products = prodGroup };
```

Comment: Complementando: seria possível acessar a variável category do join caso a cláusula into não precisasse ser utilizada. Esta clausula oculta as variáveis utilizadas para compor seu resultado.